# LWC click event listener only capturing clicks within my utility component

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have an LWC utility and would like to capture clicks not only in the utility itself but **anywhere** on the webpage. I have an event listener which works to this effect in Chrome. However, in Firefox, Opera, and Edge the clicks are only captured if they occur inside the utility itself or the utility bar. I have tried setting the listener on both document and window to no avail. I have also tried using the capture param when setting the listener, also to no effect.

Here is the relevant part of my controller:

```
lastClick = new Date().getTime();

clickHandler = () => {
    this.lastClick = new Date().getTime();
    console.log('lastClick: ' + this.lastClick);
}

connectedCallback() {
    document.addEventListener('click',this.clickHandler,true);
}

disconnectedCallback() {
    document.removeEventListener('click',this.clickHandler);
}
```

Any idea how to overcome these browsers' idiosyncrasy?

UPDATE: looks like it's not the browsers - they actually behave consistently. It's that Visualforce pages don't log the clicks (and I happened to be testing on a VF page in those three browsers). Looks like everything that's part of the native LEx framework, on the other hand, does.

Why would VF pages be an exception?

Comment: Are you using Locker Service or Lightning Web Security?

Comment: @sfdcfox no on both.

Comment: @sfdcfox looks like I was wrong about the browsers being the issue. It's that VF pages in particular don't register clicks, probably because of how they are framed. I'll update the question.